# Formatting Select String Output

Tags: powershell

I am trying to format my output like shown below :

Source files:

`a.txt`:

```
website is : "rent.com/test"
```

`b.txt`:

```
"rent.com/"
```

`c.txt`:

```
rent.com
```

Output Should be (format: `file ~ linenumber~ line ~matched value`):

```
D:\test\a.txt~1~website is : "rent.com/test"~rent.com/test"
```

Output I am getting:

```
D:\test\a.txt~1~website is : "rent.com/test"~System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[]
D:\test\b.txt~1~"rent.com/"~System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[]
```

Code:

```
$pat = @('rent.com/.\+"')
$files = Get-ChildItem "D:\test\*.*" -Recurse
$files |
    Select-String -Pattern $pat |
    %{ "{0}~{1}~{2}~{3}" -f $_.Path, $_.LineNumber, $_.Line ,$_.Matches } |
    Out-File "D:\output\result.txt"
```

Two problems:

- How do I get just the matched value along with the line as well?
- Why does my pattern `rent.com/.\+` match String `"rent.com/"`?

Comment: `$.Matches` -> `$($.Matches)`. P.S. Why pattern `rent.com/.+` should not match string `rent.com/"`?

Comment: Is your pattern really `rent.com/.\+"`, or is it `rent.com/.+`?

Comment: The only explanation I have for a regular expression `rent.com/.+"` matching a string `"rent.com/"` is some weird zero-width Unicode character between the forward slash and the double quote.

Comment: $($_.Matches) works.  Thanks @PetSerAI  . Problem 1 solved

Comment: As for the pattern , I tried using \brent.com/.+\b" which doesn't match "rent.com/" ; but again it matches the string - 'rent.com/test" method="POST" '